# Erro Cannot GET /index.html Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: Estrutura da aplicação]

[image: Codigo do servidor]

[image: Servidor a correr]

[image: Quando tento aceder a página index.html]

Penso que o problema esteja na atribuição de rotas, coisa que fui tentando fazer mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Nao tem nenhuma rota renderizando essa pagina. Falta a rota para esse index.html. Por exemplo `app.get('/index', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html')
})`.

Comment: Fiz esta rota app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    res.sendfile('./index.html') 
}) e quando tento aceder localhost:3000/index.html continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Da uma pesquisada como carrega arquivo html puro, eu faço uso de view engine, então nao é mesma coisa para renderizar o html. Tem q fazer o load da pasta public no express para carregar o que há dentro dela também.

Comment: Seguindo o comentário do amigo acima, você deve acessar "http://localhost:3000/index" e não "http://localhost:3000/index.html". A rota que foi criada é "/index" e não "/index.html".

Answer (score 1):

Boas Alexandre,

eu acho que o problema o facto de o ficheiro "index.html" não estar a ser enviado a quando da requisição GET.

```
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score 1):

Coloque este pedaço de código:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Mas eu recomendo fortemente servir arquivos estáticos dentro de uma pasta, para mais organização do código:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.listen(3000);
```

Os arquivos .html ficarão dentro da pasta `/public`.
Nos dois exemplos, você irá acessar em http://localhost:3000

Mas, caso você queira acessar, por exemplo: http://localhost:3000/site, você irá usar `app.use("/site", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`, assim:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use("/site", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.listen(3000);
```

Acesse http://localhost:3000/site

No primeiro argumento da função `use`, é o endereço da endpoint que será acessada pelo usuário, E no segundo argumento é o local dos arquivos estáticos que serão servidos pro cliente.

Para você entender melhor ainda, se você colocar "/site/api/v2" em vez de "/site", você irá acessar a seguinte URL: http://localhost:3000/site/api/v2
e se você colocar `path.join(__dirname, "public", "static")`, em seu projeto você colocará os arquivos estáticos em `/public/static` (arquivos `.html`, `.css`, `.js`, entre outros)

É isso. :)